# ViewPage.addOnPageChangeListener method cannot be resolved

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want to add an OnPageChangeListener to my ViewPager. I am using compileSdkversion 24. 
But when i try to use the addOnpageChangeListener method it cant be resolved:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(PageListener);
```

but when i use the setOnpageChangeListener method it works fine:

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(PageListener);
```

But should I use the add method?

Comment: Are you importing the latest support library?

Comment: `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'` is the one that i use

Comment: How do you initialize your viewPager and PageListener? What exactly Android Studio says about error?

Comment: `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener PageListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {`

Comment: Can't resolve method 'addOnpageChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener'

Answer (score 0):

i use this code and it worcks . you may chenge your class methods

```
     mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```